# Indian visa registration requirements - stay duration or visa duration?

Tags: visas, india, regulations, registration

I've just got a new visa for India, which contains the Endorsement:

> STAY DURING EACH VISIT NOT TO EXCEED 180 DAYS

Then, just below that, it says:

> Registration Required within 14 days of arrival in India for Visas Valid for more than 180 days

My visa is a 2 year, multiple entry tourist+business visa

.

It isn't clear to me if I need to register or not? Does the registration requirements apply for visas which are valid for stays of >180 days? (Which mine isn't) Or does it apply to visas where the Date of Expiry is >180 days from the Date of Issue? (Which mine is)

If my visa does need registration, would that be on all trips? Or only trips which last more than 14 days?

Answer (score 2):

According to clause b in [this document](http://boi.gov.in/sites/default/files/RegForeigners-11.pdf) on India's Bureau of Immigration [website](http://boi.gov.in/)

> Foreigners other than those mentioned above will not be required to
>   get themselves registered, even if they have entered India on a long
>   term visa provided their continuous stay in India does not exceed 180
>   days. If the intention of the foreigner is to stay in India for more
>   than 180 days, he/she should get himself/ herself registered well
>   before the expiry of 180 days from the date of arrival with the
>   FRRO/FRO concerned.

So it looks like only Pakistan and Afghan nationals need to get registered if they stay is less than 180 days for long term Visas.

Then there is a another clause (clause d) later in the document mentioning about Business Visas

> Registration is also required in the case of visa less than 180 days
>   and if there is special endorsement "for registration required".
>   However foreigners entering on Entry(X) and Business visas valid for
>   more than 180 days are required to register with the FRRO, FRO if they
>   continuously intend to stay for more than 6 months i.e. more than 180
>   days on each visit. (But exempting visa bearing endorsement as "Stay
>   not to exceed 180days hence no registration required).

Assuming you are a UK citizen (based on your profile) and there is no special endorsement on your Visa as mentioned above, you wouldn't need to go through registration if your stay is less than 180 days during each visit.

Answer (score 1):

My friends on long stay visas in India (either student or work visa) DID have to get registered with the FRO within 14 days of arrival to the country because they intended to remain in the country for more than 6 months.

I had a tourist visa for 6 months and didn't have to get registered. As far as i was told it is the duration of your stay (not your visa) what matters. In any case  I strongly advise you to go to the FRO even if in doubt. Indian authorities are not particularly known for their efficiency and they can effectively preventing you from exiting the country for this.